# Не меняется дата создания у файла

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, администрирование, файловая-система

Есть файловый сервер на котором выделили шару, на нем необходимо поменять дату создания файла на более позднюю.

Например, на 2017 год.

Так вот, проблема в том, что эта дата автоматически сбрасывается в текущую дату, хотя дата последнего доступа и дата последний записи успешно меняется.

На локальном компьютере, где стоит Windows 7 все успешно меняется, на сервере под Windows 2003 все успешно меняется по шаре, а на сторонней шаре не менятся.

Даже пробовал файл 2017 года кидать на шару, так все равно сбрасывалась дата до 2016...

Дату пытаюсь менять самопальной программой.

Гугл молчит...

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Может это какая-то политика безопасности или может быть целевой сервер вообще не под управлением Windows?

**UPD**

Дата создания все таки меняется, но только в прошлое. Т.е 2013 год я спокойно могу поставить, а 2017 сбросится до 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно стандарту POSIX (а, по всей видимости, сервер обслуживается вариантом OS UNIX), в структуре дескриптора файла должны присутствовать следующие поля, связанные с временем:

```
struct stat /* структура, возвращаемая stat */
{
. . . 
time_t st_atime;  /* время последнего чтения из файла */
time_t st_mtime;  /* время последней записи в файл */ 
time_t st_ctime;  /* время последнего изменения файла или индексного  дескриптора */
};
```

Как видите, никакого времени СОЗДАНИЯ файла здесь нет. И это - совершенно правильно. Что бы в этом убедиться, подумайте вот над каким вопросом: Вы переименовали файл А (может быть - переслали его в другой каталог) именем В. Что есть дата СОЗДАНИЯ файла В? У Вас есть внятный ответ на этот вопрос? Такого ответа никто пока не придумал :-) А то, что в Windows называется датой СОЗДАНИЯ файла - оставим это на совести Билла Гейтса :-)

Comment: А можно какую-нибудь команду послать серверу со стороны Windows, что бы узнать тип ОС на другой стороне?

Comment: Я вспомнил, еще интересную особенность. Дата создания все таки меняется, но только в прошлое.

Comment: **узнать тип ОС на другой стороне? ** - Например, так: nmap -sS -O -vv example.com Насколько мне известно, есть версия nmap для Windows. example.com - это URL Вашей шары.

Comment: Кстати, если натравить  эту команду на сервер microsoft.com, то мы узнаем, что этот сервер работает под управлением Symbian OS :-) Это не шутка...